# ArgumentNullException in C# setter

Tags: c#, setter, argumentnullexception

I´ve got the following code:

```
private string _email;
public string email
{
    get { return _email; }
    set
    {
        try
        {
            MailAddress m = new MailAddress(email);
            this._email = email;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong email format");
        }
    }
}
```

I've been investigating and this should be the way to do it roughly, but for some reason a ArgumentNullException is always being thrown.

Comment: What does `MailAddress`'s constructor look like?

Comment: I assume you mean a `NullReferenceException`... but it's not at all clear why the code you've shown would throw that, unless it's within the `MailAddress` constructor. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I think the setter has to use `value` but not `email`.  Thats it, the parameter name is `value`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w86s7x04.aspx

Comment: @JoseLuis You are right buddy

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry Jon, I wasn´t clear at all, I mean an ArgumentNullException

Comment: As an aside, I'd also *strongly* advise you to follow .NET naming conventions, so your property would be called `Email`, not `email`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you are using the property getter within the  setter of same property and `MailAddress` will give `NullReferenceException` if Address passed in constructor is null. Rather you should use `value`

```
    public string email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                MailAddress m = new MailAddress(value);
                this._email = value;
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Wrong email format");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setter is wrong, you are setting the property back by using again property getter which is obviously `null`, you need to use `value` like:

```
try
  {
      MailAddress m = new MailAddress(value);
      this._email = value;
  }
  catch (FormatException)
  {
      throw new ArgumentException("Wrong email format");
  }
```